# Regex if more than two line to two line else one line

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var y = document.querySelectorAll("pre code");
for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  y[i].innerHTML = y[i].innerHTML.replace("\n", "");
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing HighlightJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/styles/routeros.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing HighlightJS</h3>
    <h4>CSS</h4>
    <pre><code class="language-css">
    .class{
    font-size: 0.85rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    
    h1 .header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;;
    font-family: Arial;
    }
    </code></pre>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/10.6.0/languages/css.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlightjs-line-numbers.js/2.6.0/highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js"></script>
    <script>hljs.highlightAll(); hljs.initLineNumbersOnLoad();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This could be trivial, but I am not able to find or resolve.

If more than two line break, then two line break, else one-line break.

What I could write is :

```
.replace(\[\r\n]{2, } ? \n\n, "\n\n ? \n")
```

But this is giving error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match 3 or more linebreaks, and replace with 2 newlines or match 2 newlines using an alternation and replace that with 1 newline.

```
((?:\r?\n){3,})|(?:\r?\n){2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5wcC9A/1)

```js
let str = `test1



test2
test3

test4`;

str = str.replace(/((?:\r?\n){3,})|(?:\r?\n){2}/g, (_, g1) => g1 ? "\n\n" : "\n");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: @BrownPaul I see, I have updated the answer. Now if there are 3 or more, you replace it with 2 newlines. If there are 2 newlines, you replace it with 1.